# How do I correct a bad sentence alignment (parallel corpus)?

Tags: alignment, corpus, sentence

I have a parallel corpus (pt-en) but it has some alignment mistakes. Usually because portuguese sentences are longer and when a translation is done by humans (gold standart) they cut the sentences in half for better understanding. This doesn't happen very offten but I need a perfect alignement to train my machine.

### Example: (1 - 1);(2, 3 - 2);(4 - 3);(5 - 4)

### EN

> 1 - Once the individuals at high risk for events are identified, we propose that they be treated according to the current prevention guidelines, mainly in regard to the use of statins and acetylsalicylic acid2.
>
> 2 - We suggest that further studies approach the determination of coronary artery calcium scores in women, assess a greater number of males at more advanced ages and of different social classes than that of the population studied (middle-class individuals).
>
> 3 - We also suggest that the coronary calcium scores reported for Brazilian populations should be compared with those of populations in the USA, because these are the patterns available in the literature.
>
> 4 - If differences are found, a prospective study about the value of coronary artery calcification in our population should be carried out.
>
> 5 - Our study is a starting point.

### PT

> 1 - Uma vez identificados os indivíduos sob risco elevado de eventos, propomos que estes sejam tratados conforme as diretrizes atuais de prevenção, principalmente, no que se refere ao uso de estatinas e ácido acetilsalicílico2.
>
> 2 - Para seguimento de nosso trabalho, tornam-se necessários determinações em mulheres, número maior de homens em idades mais avançadas e de classes sociais diferentes da população estudada (indivíduos de classe média), comparação dos escores de cálcio coronariano descritos em populações brasileiras aos dos EUA, já que esses são os padrões disponíveis na literatura.
>
> 3 - Caso haja diferenças, seria importante um estudo prospectivo do valor da calcificação arterial coronariana em nossa população.
>
> 4 - Nosso estudo é um início para esse processo.

Thanks in advance!